# Strange characters when pasted from Word in our Java app

Tags: java, swing, awt, clipboard

We have a Java application that's experiencing character encoding problems when pasting from Word into one of its text fields. This is only happening in IE8, and I assume previous IE versions. The replaceAll Java filters I initially added to fix this problem works on all of the latest browsers. IE8 is the problem.

An example of the problem:

“double quotes” is pasted from Word into a text field. After saving the entry, the quotation marks are converted into the characters below. After each new save, the characters change and the number of them increase.

First save:  âœdouble quotesâ

Second save:  Ã¢ÂÂœdouble quotesÃ¢ÂÂ

Third save:  ÃƒÂ¢Ã‚ÂÃ‚Âœdouble quotesÃƒÂ¢Ã‚ÂÃ‚Â

Fourth save:  ÃƒÂƒÃ‚Â¢ÃƒÂ‚Ã‚ÂÃƒÂ‚Ã‚Âœdouble quotesÃƒÂƒÃ‚Â¢ÃƒÂ‚Ã‚ÂÃƒÂ‚Ã‚Â

So quotation marks and apostrophes are our main concern. We'd also like to have bullet lists work well in this text field.

Comment: Could you show the code used to read data from word file?

Comment: It would help if you posted sample code and clarified what you are looking for as an answer.

Comment: Someone that I knew had this problem with a C# app of his, and it took forever to figure out what was wrong. I don't think he ever ended up fixing it, but we knew where the problem was coming from and how to avoid it.

Comment: The user is trying to paste content from Word that contains either double quotes or apostrophes, and they're being converted into these strange characters. I'm trying to find a way to prevent that conversion from happening. It's the Smart Quotes from Word that are causing the problem. I'll find the code and paste it soon.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Word does not use standard double quotes ("), they use the double quotes that change their 'direction' and look like this: “ ”. The formatted duble quotes are very different from normal double quotes, and will not appear the same when put in a normal text box.